# React Native: Redux-persist, Result of actions not being persisted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've a RN app with react-redux, redux-thunk and redux-persist.

everything was fine, I've changed the reducers and added new actions. But unfortunately state is not being persisted any more. Whatever action I trigger, after reloading the app, i see it's not persisted.

What could cause it?

here is my actions/reducers :

```js
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';
import {Actions as routes} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export const types = {
  GET_COURSES: 'GET_COURSES',
  AUTHENTICATE: 'AUTHENTICATE',
  AUTHENTICATE_FAILED: 'AUTHENTICATE_FAILED',
  GET_EVALUATION: 'GET_EVALUATION',
  GET_EVALUATION_FAILED: 'GET_EVALUATION_FAILED',
  SUBMIT_EVALUATION: 'SUBMIT_EVALUATION',
  SUBMIT_EVALUATION_FAILED: 'SUBMIT_EVALUATION_FAILED',
  BOOK_COURSE: 'BOOK_COURSE',
  UNBOOK_COURSE: 'UNBOOK_COURSE',
  BOOK_COURSE_FAILED: 'BOOK_COURSE_FAILED',
  UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED: 'UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED'
};

import Functions from './common/Functions';


export const actionCreators = {
  getEvaluations: (users) => {
    return dispatch => {
      Functions.getEvaluationsAPI(users)
      .then((data)=>{
        const {evaluationsList} = data;
        return dispatch(evaluationSuccess(evaluationsList));
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        return dispatch(evaluationFailed(e));
      });
    }
  },
  getCourses: (users) => {
    console.log('getting courses, user', users);
    return dispatch => {
      Functions.getCoursesAPI(users)
      .then((data)=>{
        const {courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray} = data;
        return dispatch(coursesSuccess(courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray));
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        return dispatch(coursesFailed(e));
      });
    }
  },
  bookCourse: (user, courseId, callback) => {
    return dispatch => {
      Functions.bookCourse(user, courseId, callback)
      .then(()=>{
        Functions.getCoursesAPI([user])
        .then((data)=>{
          const {courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray} = data;
          return dispatch(coursesSuccess(courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray));
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          return dispatch(coursesFailed(e));
        });
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        return dispatch(coursesFailed(e));
      })
    }
  },
  unbookCourse: (user, courseId, callback) => {
    return dispatch => {
      Functions.unbookCourse(user, courseId, callback)
      .then(()=>{
        Functions.getCoursesAPI([user])
        .then((data)=>{
          const {courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray} = data;
          return dispatch(coursesSuccess(courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray));
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          return dispatch(coursesFailed(e));
        });
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        return dispatch(coursesFailed(e));
      })
    }
  },
  submitEvaluation: (user, users, evaluationId, evaluationData, callback) => {
    return dispatch => {
      Functions.submitEvaluation(user, users, evaluationId, evaluationData, callback)
      .then(()=>{
        Functions.getEvaluationsAPI(users)
        .then((data)=>{
          const {evaluationsList} = data;
          return dispatch(evaluationSuccess(evaluationsList));
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          return dispatch(evaluationFailed(e));
        });
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        return dispatch(evaluationSubmissionFailed(e));
      })
    }
  },
  authenticate: (logincode, callback) => {
    return dispatch => {
    Functions.login(logincode)
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('authenticate results:', response);
        return dispatch(loginSuccess(response));
      })
      .then(()=>{
        routes.tabbar();
      })
      .catch((e)=>{
        console.log('authenticate error:', e);
        callback(e.message);
        return dispatch(loginFailed(e.message));
      })
   }
  }
}

const loginSuccess = (response) => {
 return {
  type: types.AUTHENTICATE,
  payload: response
 };
};
const loginFailed = (response) => {
 return {
  type: types.AUTHENTICATE_FAILED,
  payload: {
   error: response
  }
 };
};

const evaluationSuccess = (evaluationsList) => {
  return {
    type: types.GET_EVALUATION,
    payload: {
      evaluations: evaluationsList
    }
  };
};

const evaluationFailed = (e) => {
  return {
    type: types.GET_EVALUATION_FAILED,
    payload: {
      error: e
    }
  };
};

const evaluationSubmissionSuccess = (evaluationsList) => {
  return {
    type: types.SUBMIT_EVALUATION,
    payload: {
      evaluatiosn: evaluationsList
    }
  };
};

const evaluationSubmissionFailed = (e) => {
  return {
    type: types.SUBMIT_EVALUATION_FAILED,
    payload: {
      error: e
    }
  };
};

const coursesSuccess = (courses, lectures, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray) => {
  return {
    type: types.GET_COURSES,
    payload: {
      courses: courses,
      lectures: lectures,
      schedule: schedule,
      events: eventList,
      discussion: discussion,
      coursesArray: coursesArray
    }
  };
};

const coursesFailed = (e) => {
  return {
    type: types.GET_COURSES_FAILED,
    payload: {
      error: e
    }
  };
};

const initialState = {
  rehydrated: false,
  user: null,
  login: false,
  users: {},
  courses: {},
  schedules: {},
  evaluations: {},
  lectures: {},
  goals: {},
  discussions: {},
  attendance: {},
  events: {}
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {user, users, courses, login, schedules, evaluations, goals, discussions, attendance, events, lectures} = state;
  const {type, payload} = action;

  switch (type) {
    case types.GET_COURSES: {
      return {
        ...state,
        courses: payload.coursesArray,
        lectures: payload.lectures,
        schedules: payload.schedule,
        events: payload.events,
        discussions: payload.discussion
      }
    }
    case types.GET_COURSES_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.AUTHENTICATE: {
      let newObj = users;
      newObj[payload.userId] = payload;
      let newCourses = courses;
      newCourses[payload.userId] = [];
      let newschedules = schedules;
      newschedules[payload.userId] = [];
      let newevaluations = evaluations;
      newevaluations[payload.userId] = [];
      let newgoals = goals;
      newgoals[payload.userId] = [];
      let newdiscussions = discussions;
      newdiscussions[payload.userId] = [];
      let newattendance = attendance;
      newattendance[payload.userId] = [];
      let neweventList = events;
      neweventList[payload.userId] = [];
      let newlectures = lectures;
      newlectures[payload.userId] = [];

      return {
        ...state,
        login: true,
        user: payload.userId,
        users: newObj,
        courses: newCourses,
        schedules: newschedules,
        evaluations: newevaluations,
        goals: newgoals,
        discussions: newdiscussions,
        attendance: newattendance,
        events: neweventList,
        lectures: newlectures
      }
    }
    case types.AUTHENTICATE_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.GET_EVALUATION: {
      return {
        ...state,
        evaluations: payload.evaluations
      }
    }
    case types.GET_EVALUATION_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.SUBMIT_EVALUATION: {
      return {
        ...state,
        evaluations: payload.evaluations
      }
    }
    case types.SUBMIT_EVALUATION_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.BOOK_COURSE: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.BOOK_COURSE_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.UNBOOK_COURSE: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case types.UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state
      }
    }
    case REHYDRATE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        rehydrated: true
      }
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

****UPDATE :
store configuration :

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import { reducer } from './reducers'
import Routes from './Routes'

const logger = createLogger();

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
  applyMiddleware(
    thunk,
    logger
  )
), autoRehydrate({ log: true }))

persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage})


const Root = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Routes />
  </Provider>
)

export default Root
```

Comment: @JaseemAbbas I've updated the question with store.js

Comment: @JaseemAbbas for GET_EVALUATION it was return {
        ...state,
        evaluations: payload.evaluations
      } I changed it to return Object.assign({}, state, {
        evaluations: payload.evaluations
      }).

is that right?

Comment: It should be Object.assign(...state, payload.evaluations)

Comment: @JaseemAbbas it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Add window.store = store; below persistStore(...) in your store.js. Open your  dev tools. After you perform an action, before refresh, try window.getState().store and check if the values are getting stored. It might help in better debugging.

Comment: Window.getState? Can i use it in react native app? Its not react for web.

Comment: Yes you can. I am currently developing a react native app where I am using this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135272/discussion-between-jaseem-abbas-and-ataomega).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, you are trying to dispatch an action, but your view does not update. Why does this happen? There may be several reasons for this.

**Never mutate reducer arguments**

Every single time, you must return the new state object. Even if you don't use a library like Immutable, you need to completely avoid mutation.

For example, a reducer like this is wrong because it mutates the state:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      // Wrong! This mutates state
      state.push({
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      })
      return state
    case 'COMPLETE_TODO':
      // Wrong! This mutates state[action.index].
      state[action.index].completed = true
      return state
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

It needs to be rewritten like this:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      // Return a new array
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'COMPLETE_TODO':
      // Return a new array
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          // Copy the object before mutating
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: true
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

It's more code, but it's exactly what makes Redux predictable and efficient.

**Don't forget to call dispatch(action)**

Don't forget to call dispatch(action)

**Make sure mapStateToProps is correct**

It's possible you're correctly dispatching an action and applying your reducer but the corresponding state is not being correctly translated into props.

Here's a complete [troubleshooting article](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html) from redux for the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already read that docs at redux. as you can see in my code, I'm trying to return a new object every time. also tried the Object.assign but no success :(